# I need to pull an individual string from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need to pull a piece of data from.  I didn't write the original code that creates the array and it doesn't seem to act like I expect it to and my array knowledge is growing but still fairly new. 
Here is the array:

```
array(31) { ["title"]=> string(13) "Title of work" ["abstr"]=> string(163) "
Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum.

" ["outcomes"]=> string(163) "
Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum.

" ["CategorySelection"]=> string(11) "Application" ["research3"]=> string(0) "" ["research4"]=> string(0) "" ["research5"]=> string(0) "" ["research6"]=> string(0) "" ["innovation3"]=> string(0) "" ["innovation4"]=> string(0) "" ["innovation5"]=> string(0) "" ["innovation6"]=> string(0) "" ["application3"]=> string(308) "
The university has invited proposals from national food management services to potentially provide Miami with one or two directors to guide day-to-day management for university dining and to assist in refining and strengthening the strategic direction for our nationally recognized dining operation.

" ["application4"]=> string(308) "
The university has invited proposals from national food management services to potentially provide Miami with one or two directors to guide day-to-day management for university dining and to assist in refining and strengthening the strategic direction for our nationally recognized dining operation.

" ["application5"]=> string(308) "
The university has invited proposals from national food management services to potentially provide Miami with one or two directors to guide day-to-day management for university dining and to assist in refining and strengthening the strategic direction for our nationally recognized dining operation.

" ["application6"]=> string(308) "
The university has invited proposals from national food management services to potentially provide Miami with one or two directors to guide day-to-day management for university dining and to assist in refining and strengthening the strategic direction for our nationally recognized dining operation.

" ["integration3"]=> string(0) "" ["integration4"]=> string(0) "" ["integration5"]=> string(0) "" ["integration6"]=> string(0) "" ["references"]=> string(154) "Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum. " ["organization"]=> string(154) "Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum. " ["flipchart"]=> string(3) "yes" ["video"]=> string(3) "yes" ["comments"]=> string(154) "Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum. Souvlaki ignitus carborundum e pluribus unum. " ["type"]=> string(11) "contributed" ["infocheck"]=> string(3) "Yes" ["presenters"]=> string(224) "[Doe, Jane undefined] middle_name = sldk department = sldkf institution = lksdj city = lsldkf state = lskdf country = slkdf office_phone = 123-456-7891 cell_phone = email_address = email@address.com website = " ["user_agent"]=> string(121) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36" ["keywords"]=> string(39) " Blackboard Civic Engagement Cognition " ["requested_format"]=> string(24) "Panel, 40-minute, Poster" }
```

I can figure out how to pull and echo variables like title, etc. and even the whole presenters array within the top level array, but I cannot extract the email address from the presenters array.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your array sits in a variable, ie `$array`. You can refer to title as `$array['title']`. What you show here is a dump of the array.

Comment: Presenters (`$array('presenters']`) is not an array, it's a string. You will need some way to parse it. I suggest regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry, I should have indicated that I was posting the dump. I though that would be useful. What I currently have is  echo $output['presenters']; that will echo the nested array.  I can't figure out how to just pull the email.

Comment: Thank you for that, @CompuChip .  I was thinking string, but couldn't figure out the extraction.  I appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is formatted weirdly, but I guess the value of presenters is a long string with values.

To get the email address use the following:

```
$strPresenters = $baseArray['presenters']; //actually I can't even track how to get to presenters, but you can figure that out with trial and error
preg_match('/email_address = ([^\s]*)/', $strPresenters, $aryMatch);
$strEmail = $aryMatch[1];
```

You may have to tweak that regex if the format varies at all.

Comment: Got it! That was the little kick I needed.  This shows the email address perfectly: $strPresenters = $output['presenters']; 
preg_match('/email_address = ([^\s]*)/', $strPresenters, $aryMatch);
$strEmail = $aryMatch[1];
echo var_dump($strEmail);